# LM2596S-ADJ buck converter circuit heating up and wasting a lot of voltage somewhere

Tags: voltage, integrated-circuit, dc-dc-converter, buck, variable

I've built my own DIY adjustable buck converter using a Teensy, a gate driver, and all manner of components. It worked OK (I was able to vary voltage from 20 mV all the way up to about 20 V when my input power was 24 V) but I had an overheating problem.

I assumed my calculations of the components were off or my wiring was crap. I'm very new to this power electronics business. So I decided to literally follow a set out circuit:

[image]

At PSU = 24 V, the max. voltage I can get on the load is only about 12.5 V and the current shown by the PSU is about 0.850 A. Meanwhile, the LM2596S begins getting hot.

At PSU = 15 V, the max. voltage I can get across the load is 12.69 V and the current shown by the PSU is about 1.285 A. The LM2596S isn't getting hot, just warm.

What is going on here? I'm using a  [TENMA 72-10495](https://uk.farnell.com/tenma/72-10495/power-supply-2ch-30v-5a-adjustable/dp/2251947) PSU.

Is it my diode? Or is it my load? Or is it the fact that I'm using long wires from my PSU (IN) and long wires to my physical load (OUT)? Everything else on the circuit is soldered as closely as possible:

[image]

So why can I not vary the voltage on my load nearer to 24 V if I set the PSU at 24 V? Why is my LM still getting so hot in that setup? I literally followed a schematic and instructions that said I should be able to vary my power from 1.2 V - 40 V depending on the PSU power. But if I put it at 24 V, literally 12 V is lost somewhere and my LM starts burning up and producing a chemical smell.

What is wrong now, can anyone advise me?

Comment: What kind of load are you using, and what current is your inductor rated for?

Comment: What inductor and diode are you using. Show a picture of your setup.

Comment: @Andyaka He showed his schematic with components, though looking at the physical size, I wonder how much current that 68 uH inductor can handle.

Answer (score 1):

The datasheet for the LM2596 gives the following formula for the output voltage of the adjustable version:

\$V_{OUT} = V_{REF} \cdot (1+\frac{R_2}{R_1}) \$ where \$V_{REF} = 1.23\$

You have R1 as 10k ohms. Assuming the max value of R2 at 100k, the maximum output for your setup is 13.53 volts. Perhaps that is why your voltage is not approaching VIN. Try swapping out the 10k resistor with the recommended 1k ohm value.